# Correctly using MOD operator in ARM GAS assembler

Tags: gnu-assembler

I'm trying to use the mod operator but get an error.

```
Error: garbage following instruction -- `mov r0,r5 MOD#3'
```

The program is simple:

```
    mov r5, #0
    add r5, #1
    mov r0, r5 MOD #3
    cmp r0, #0
```

The example they give in the Keil documentation is this:

```
MOV     R1,#12 MOD 7   ; R1 = 5
```

As you can see I'm simply trying to see if the value in r5 is evenly divisible by 3. I've got the wrong syntax, but can't seem to find the correct syntax for Gnu As.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a subtraction function to determine if there was a remainder.